# How to setSize JButtons in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to fix this issue in my `JPanel`.

I want to set sizes of `0` and `=` JButtons in `JPanel`.  Other button sizes are the same but `0` and `=` are bit long vertically and horizontally (like MS windows Calculator). How do I set it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that by using `GridBagLayout` layout manager.

> A GridBagLayout places components in a grid of rows and columns, allowing specified components to span multiple rows or columns. Not all rows necessarily have the same height. Similarly, not all columns necessarily have the same width.

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Comment: Yeah I also think Gridbaglayout can answer my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the layout used respects the preferred size of the buttons, a larger button can easily be had one of three ways:

1. Set a larger size of `Font`
2. Give the button a larger `Icon`
3. Call `setMargin(Insets)` with a large margin.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want a hassle, try using WindowsBuilder on Eclipse. You can edit it on a design interface, and the codes will be generated.

Comment: You're just trading a small hassle for a larger hassle when you use a window builder of any kind.

Comment: Thanks but I want to code this on notepad. Thank you for the response again :)